# ES2015 Singleton or Service Provider or Module for Knockout.js components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, singleton, repository-pattern, babeljs

I have a large number of knockout components, which are currently using KO.postbox to communicate.

I now want to create a central service provider / repository / singleton which centrally stores data for and provides initialization and api and other functions for all of these components.

The page is only one window / session, but each one has 3-7 Knockout components and in some cases the same component is loaded multiple times on the page.  The result is a lot of chatter between the component that has loaded data via API and those that also need the same data.

My current approach is to use the singleton pattern (other approaches happily considered).  The only non-changeable requirements are:

1. Store and retrieve data from one central "repository" for multiple KO components
2. Written in ES2015 and able to work with Babel
3. Loadable and exportable as a module

The problem with the current code is

a. This is set to undefined by babel, e.g. `this.instance = null` raises an error of cannot set instance of undefined.
b. I am not really sure this is the best method or that I can make it work

The code is below

```
const ko = require('knockout')
    , moment = require('moment')
    , postbox = require('knockout-postbox')
    , aja = require('aja');


const myServiceSingleton = () =>{ 

    this.instance = null;
    this.array1 = ko.observable([]);
    this.array2 = ko.observable([]);

    // revealing module pattern that handles initialization of our new singleton service provider
    const initializeNewModule = () => {

        const setArray1 = (array) => {
            console.info( 'Set Array1 Called' );
            this.array1(array);
        };

        const getArray1 = () => {
            console.info( 'Get Array1 Called' );
            return this.array1();
        };

        const setArray2 = (array) => {
            console.info( 'Set Array2 Called' );
            this.array2(array);
        };

        const getArray2 = () => {
            console.info( 'Get Array2 Called' );
            return this.array2();
        };

        const myAwesomeFunction = () => {
            // Perform some amazing computations on Array1 and Array 2
        };

        return {
            setArray1 : setArray1,
            getArray1 : getArray1,
            setArray2 : setArray2,
            getArray2 : getArray2,
            myAwesomeFunction : myAwesomeFunction
        };
    };

    // handles the prevention of additional instantiations
    const getInstance = () => {
        if( ! this.instance ) {
            this.instance = new initializeNewModule();
        }
        return this.instance;
    };

    return {
        getInstance : getInstance
    };

};
module.exports = myServiceSingleton;
```

---------EDIT----------

In the hopes this helps someone else...

```
const ko = require('knockout')
    , moment = require('moment')
    , postbox = require('knockout-postbox')
    , aja = require('aja');

const array1 = ko.observable([]);
const array2 = ko.observable([]);
const secretFlag = ko.observable(false);

const myAmazingSingleton = {

    setArray1(newArray) {
        console.info( newArray);
        array1(newArray);
    },

    getArray1() {
        console.info( 'Get Array1 Called' );
        return array1();
    },

    getArray2() {
        return array2();
    },

    setArray2(newArray) {
        console.info('Set Array2 Called');
        array2(newArray);
    },

    getArray1Observable() {
        return array1 ;
    },

    myAwesomeFunction() {
        // Perform some amazing computations on Array1 and Array 2
        array1.map //etc etc
    }
};

export default myAmazingSingleton ;
```

To use is quite simple:

```
import ArrayFunctions from 'myAmazingSingleton';
let array1 = ArrayFunctions.getArray1();
```

And the data is available across multiple Knockout components

Comment: `() =>{ // Not an arrow function` - huh?

Comment: Ignore comment - that was a bit of old code I forgot to tidy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an arrow function as a constructor. You really should just use a simple object literal:

```
const myServiceSingleton = {
    array1: ko.observable([]),
    array2: ko.observable([]),
    setArray1(array) {
        console.info( 'Set Array1 Called' );
        this.array1(array);
    },
    getArray1() {
        console.info( 'Get Array1 Called' );
        return this.array1();
    },
    setArray2(array) {
        console.info( 'Set Array2 Called' );
        this.array2(array);
    },
    getArray2() {
        console.info( 'Get Array2 Called' );
        return this.array2();
    },
    myAwesomeFunction() {
        // Perform some amazing computations on Array1 and Array 2
    }
};
```

If you insist, you can make an

```
export function getInstance() {
    return myServiceSingleton;
}
```

or even lazy-initialise it, but usually you should just `export default` it.

Comment: Presumably  array1 and array2 are both exposed, so instead of calling `myServiceSingleton.getArray1()` I or anyone else on the team could just use `myServiceSingleton.array1()`. So the object literal should work, but what would be a good way to make the data private?

Comment: Importing the myServiceSingleton object literal works across the KO components, but each import appears to bring in its own new version rather than a singleton. Im am using `export {myServiceSingleton}` and `import {myServiceSingleton} from `myServiceSingleton`. For examples `myServiceSingleton.array1.subscribe` never triggers.  Should this happen? Have I got Babel/Browserify set up wrong?

Comment: If you want to make your data private, just use local variables (on the module level). You can't use `this.arrayN()` then, of course.

Comment: Yes, this should work, ES6 modules are supposed to be only instantiated once per realm. No idea what could be wrong with the setup, though.

Comment: I decided it could be `{ }` around the import and export, but removing them makes no difference.  However, I noticed that calling setArray is NOT generating console.info so I will have a look as it may be that KO has taken offence at the babel/browserify object literal

Comment: KO was in the end happy - some of the elements were not binding simply because in debugging I forgot to select them. Merci!

Answer (score 1):

I think the singleton you want to use is a master viewmodel, by which I mean just the usual way of setting up Knockout. Use the components' `params` to pass from the master viewmodel any observables that your components need to share.

Comment: I believe you are right if I don't use the code on multiple pages or at the very least can use the same master viewmodel on those multiple pages. But if I need the functionality (or a portion of it) for other viewmodels then that makes the decision a bit harder.  Many thanks for coming back quickly, and I am going to think this through :)

Comment: Any code that needs to be re-used can be made its own module which the master viewmodel for the application would import. The master VM would still handle passing relevant bits to components.

Comment: I have opted for the object literal pattern, but ticked your answer as well because I will be able to use that for each page that acts as an SPA